# Setting exposure property of webcam in rooted android mobile

Tags: android

I have been looking to set autoexposure off in the webcam attached to my rooted Android mobile. I have tried to solve this problem using the OpenCv library for Linux and using v4l2. But I have got no success with it.

while using v4l2, it says that it's not a v4l2 device; i.e,it gives an EINVAL error.
But this webcam is running well on other platforms...

Can anyone help me to get this problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not require rooting...

After spending around 5 days on it,I found that my webcam supported UVC.All functionalities of webcam can be implemented using UVC library "libuvc".It is an open-source project.You can get the source code [here](https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc).
Auto-exposure property of webcam can be set using following two functions defined in library::

> uvc_set_ae_mode(uvc_device_handle_t *devh, uint8_t mode);
>   uvc_set_exposure_abs(uvc_device_handle_t *devh, uint32_t time);

First method is used to set auto-exposure off/on(Setting **mode=1** makes auto-exposure **off**).The latter method is used to set absolute exposure value.

---

You can get whole list of functions and their usage [here](https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc/blob/master/include/libuvc/libuvc.h)